# Remove extra properties from object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

What would be the best way to remove any additional properties from an object that is not defined in defaults object?

```
var 

defaults = {

    color : 'blue',
    size: 9,
    price : 40.00,
    instock : true

},

newItem = {

    color: 'red',
    size : 4,
    price : 20.00
    extra : invalid // discard this
    extra1 : invalid // discard this

},

item = $.extend( defaults, newObject ) ;
```

**Desired output....**

```
{
    color : 'red',
    size: 4,
    price : 20.00,
    instock : true

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting property from object in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983710/deleting-property-from-object-in-javascript)

Comment: so use reduce or delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this performance comparison:
https://jsperf.com/dictionary-contains-key

The most efficient way to do this is:

```
for(attr in newItem) {
  if(defaults[attr] === undefined)
    delete newItem[attr];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could reduce `Object.keys(defaults)` to an object containing either the override value or the default value:

```js
var defaults = {

    color : 'blue',
    size: 9,
    price : 40.00,
    instock : true

},
newItem = {

    color: 'red',
    size : 4,
    price : 20.00,
    extra : 'invalid',
    extra1 : 'invalid'

};

function getOverrides(defaults, obj) {
    return Object.keys(defaults).reduce(function(result, cur) {
        result[cur] = cur in obj ? obj[cur] : defaults[cur];
        return result;
    }, {});
}

console.log(getOverrides(defaults, newItem));
```

Comment: According to jsbench, this is about 99.57% faster than all the other answers here :)

Answer (score 2):

Before you call $.extend, put the following.

```
for(variable in newItem) {
    if(!(variable in defaults)) {
        delete newItem[variable];
    }
}
```

This will loop over every key in `newItem` and check that it is also a key in `defaults`.  Note that this will modify `newItem`, so if that is not desired, you'll need to do some tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

Only merge properties which existing in `defaults` object: *(simple and supports old browsers)*

```js
var defaults = {
    color : 'blue',
    size: 9,
    price : 40.00,
    instock : true

};

var newItem = {
    color: 'red',
    size : 4,
    price : 20.00,
    extra : 'invalid', // discard this
    extra1 : 'invalid' // discard this

};

var result = {};
for (var i in defaults) {
  result[i] = newItem.hasOwnProperty(i) ? newItem[i] : defaults[i];
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some code that I have been playing with that may be of interest, and an example of how to use it with your question.

```js
'use strict';

var slice = Function.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);

var reflectAssign = function assign(target) {
  return slice(arguments, 1).every(function(source) {
    if (source == null) {
      return true;
    }
    var object = Object(source);
    return Reflect.ownKeys(object).every(function(key) {
      return Reflect.set(target, key, object[key]);
    });
  });
};

var reflectAssignHas = function(target) {
  var targetKeys = Reflect.ownKeys(target);
  return slice(arguments, 1).every(function(source) {
    if (source == null) {
      return true;
    }
    var object = Object(source);
    return targetKeys.every(function(key) {
      return Reflect.has(object, key) ? Reflect.set(target, key, object[key]) : true
    });
  });
};

var defaults = {
  color: 'blue',
  size: 9,
  price: 40.00,
  instock: true
};

var newItem = {
  color: 'red',
  size: 4,
  price: 20.00,
  extra: 'invalid', // discard this
  extra1: 'invalid' // discard this
};

var item = {};
console.log(reflectAssign(item, defaults));
console.log(reflectAssignHas(item, newItem));
console.log(item);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.9/es5-shim.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.9/es5-sham.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.35.3/es6-shim.js"></script>
```